# Exporting DIV area content in HTML using Java Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, html, export

How can export DIV area content from an HTML Page to PDF?.

Is it possible using without third-party tool, using JavaScript?.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

That is what I get: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825130/3810453  when I ask to great-magician-google  and clicked on FIRST link.

jsPDF is able to use plugins. In order to enable it to print HTML, you have to include certain plugins and therefore have to do the following:

Go to https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and download the latest Version.
Include the following Scripts in your project:

```
jspdf.js
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js
```

If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an ID, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of jsPDF. Therefore your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in a PopUp:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};

var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

For me this created a nice and tidy PDF that only included the line 'print this to pdf'.

Please note that the special element handlers only deal with IDs in the current version, which is also stated in a GitHub Issue. It states:

Because the matching is done against every element in the node tree, my desire was to make it as fast as possible. In that case, it meant "Only element IDs are matched" The element IDs are still done in jQuery style "#id", but it does not mean that all jQuery selectors are supported.

Therefore replacing '#ignorePDF' with class selectors like '.ignorePDF' did not work for me. Instead you will have to add the same handler for each and every element, which you want to ignore like:

```
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignoreElement': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  },
  '#anotherIdToBeIgnored': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

One very important thing to add is that you lose all your style information (CSS). Luckily jsPDF is able to nicely format h1, h2, h3 etc., which was enough for my purposes. Additionalyl it will only print text within text nodes, which means that it will not print the values of textareas and the like. Example:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <!-- This is printed as the element contains a textnode -->        
    <li>Print me!</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <!-- This is not printed because jsPDF doesn't deal with the value attribute -->
    <input type="textarea" value="Please print me, too!">
  </div>
</body>
```

and no, you cant print without third-party-tool