# Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have the following html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>don't print this to pdf</p>
        <div id="pdf">
            <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I want to do is to print to pdf whatever is found in the div with an id of "pdf".  This must be done using JavaScript.  The "pdf" document should then be automatically downloaded with a filename of "foobar.pdf"

I've been using jspdf to do this, but the only function it has is "text" which accepts only string values.  I want to submit HTML to jspdf, not text.

Comment: As mentioned above I do *not* want to use the "text" function.  I want to give it HTML.  Your link only deals with plain text and not html

Comment: jsPDF **does** have a `fromHTML` function; see the "HTML Renderer" example at: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score 320, accepted):

**jsPDF is able to use plugins.** In order to enable it to print HTML, you have to include certain plugins and therefore have to do the following:

1. Go to https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and download the latest Version.
2. Include the following Scripts in your project:

   - jspdf.js
   - jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
   - jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
   - jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js

If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an ID, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of jsPDF. Therefore your HTML should look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in a PopUp:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

For me this created a nice and tidy PDF that only included the line 'print this to pdf'.

Please note that the special element handlers only deal with IDs in the current version, which is also stated in a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/34). It states:

> Because the matching is done against every element in the node tree, my desire was to make it as fast as possible. In that case, it meant "Only element IDs are matched" The element IDs are still done in jQuery style "#id", but it does not mean that all jQuery selectors are supported.

Therefore replacing '#ignorePDF' with class selectors like '.ignorePDF' did not work for me. Instead you will have to add the same handler for each and every element, which you want to ignore like:

```
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignoreElement': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  },
  '#anotherIdToBeIgnored': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

From the [examples](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html) it is also stated that it is possible to select tags like 'a' or 'li'. That might be a little bit to unrestrictive for the most usecases though:

> We support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style
>   ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
>   There is no support for any other type of selectors (class, of
>   compound) at this time.

**One very important thing to add is that you lose all your style information (CSS). Luckily jsPDF is able to nicely format h1, h2, h3 etc., which was enough for my purposes. Additionally it will only print text within text nodes, which means that it will not print the values of textareas and the like. Example:**

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <!-- This is printed as the element contains a textnode -->        
    <li>Print me!</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <!-- This is not printed because jsPDF doesn't deal with the value attribute -->
    <input type="textarea" value="Please print me, too!">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess the element handler can be a class? That would be much more semantically in line with HTML5 standards. An ID not only carries too much speificity weight in CSS, it also has to be unique.

Comment: No, as far as I know, classes are no valid selectors at the moment as stated in their examples: "we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.) There is no support for any other type of selectors (class, of compound) at this time.". Still, it is possible to use tag names if that is in line with your use case and doesn't hide other important elements on your page.

Comment: On their page https://parall.ax/products/jspdf they state that they support IE6+ via a shim. Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: @snrlx can u tel me how can i pass css classes with html tags ?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible yet as far as I know.

Comment: @snrlx I get blank pdf and this error:  renderer.pdf.sHashCode is not a function

Comment: Please tell me how to implement download link or button, is it on doc.output("i need to add specific url here ?) or doc.save ? or doc.fromHtml ?

Comment: Would this also work with highcharts and other svgs?

Comment: I need no retrieve the css information also, do you know another library? @snrlx

Comment: Hey gabodev, unfortunately not. For my purposes, jsPDF was always enough.

Comment: I generated a pdf by using this js library, but it's getting blurred pdf. Actually, i have done this by getting HTML page content and convert it to DataUrl and generate PDF. 
Do you know how to increase quality of this image or pdf ?

Comment: "If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an ID" - a wonderful library, ruined by that inverted reqiurement. The OP wanted to print a single `<div>`, which could be one of hundreds - so he has to mark all the *unwanted* DOM elements??

Comment: Include also jspdf.plugin.cell.js for rendering table(s).

Comment: thanks @snrlx . Did you play with it using HTML including IMGs? I am having an issue: my IMG has a width of 100px and generated much much bigger in the PDF... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266210/jspdf-i-cant-generate-the-pdf-with-the-defined-img-dimensions-width)

Comment: @Micky: sorry but I never played with images so I can't assist you with that :/

Comment: i am using version 1.5.3 (from npm), the function fromHTML already exists in this library however I am getting the following error, 'addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added' does anyone know the plugin needed and can provide a link, thanks.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica We can select div(s) using tag and select a specific one using it's index. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, we can. But the OP wants to ***ignore*** a certain div. So, if he has 1,000 divs, he woudl have to slect 999 of them by name in order to ingore that one.

Comment: I have a big HTML, very complicated but all static having bootstrap classes and tabled. Used this method. Getting following error-
`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: This plugin might be good, but it's poorly documented. Most of the examples I see in stackoverflow don't even work.

Comment: Some table attributes like 'rowspan' and 'colspan' are not properly rendered in the printed document in my case. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: If I'm not wrong  ````doc.fromHTML```` is no longer supported

Comment: can someone tell how to add html css/styles in the print doc ?

Comment: `doc.fromHTML()` has been deprecated and replaced with `doc.html()`

Answer (score 92):

This is the simple solution. This works for me. You can use the javascript  print concept and simple save this as pdf.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="btnPrint" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lighter solution, but this dissmiss css styling :s

Comment: "and simple save this as pdf" - I missed that part. How do you do it?

Comment: This worked for me, for solving the problem of CSS styling, I created another css file called printPDF.css and added using link tag just like this in above example:
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/printPDF.css" />');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');

Comment: Some comments: 

1) You don't need an especific stylesheet for printing. In your current stylesheet, do something like:

@media print {
    .pageBreak {
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    .labelPdf {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .noPrintPdf {
        display: none;
    }
}

and use these classes as your needs.

2) .live("click", ...) doesn't work to me, so I use .on("click", ...) instead.

Comment: @DavidsonLima this code creates new window which will not see old window css. That's why it's "ignoring" css, it's not ignoring, just in new window it's not loaded. Just load it in head and it will be rendering.

Comment: Just in case any one is trying to make this happen with Angular, please put your CSS file in the assets folder.

Comment: This is not working in Firefox browser. Mostly Chrome browser shows print preview as pdf.

Comment: I am using the same solution. However, this is not "actual" html to pdf solution. The user can select a printer not PDF when the printer page popup. Is there any parameter I can enforce to print to PDF only?

Comment: @Alex Poon  yes you can save this as PDF

Comment: it does not take input values.

Comment: Is there any way we can do it through programming like with out opening print dialog we click on save button

Comment: Anyone wondering about the live() jQuery function -- it is deprecated, use on() : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_live.asp

Comment: Good idea, but do not work in mobile devices :(

Answer (score 33):

- No depenencies, pure JS
- To add CSS or images - do not use relative URLs, use full URLs `http://...domain.../path.css` or so. It creates separate HTML document and it has no context of main thing.
- you can also embed images as base64

This served me for years now:

```
export default function printDiv({divId, title}) {
  let mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');

  mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>${title}</title>`);
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

Of course this will open print dialog and user will have to know she/he can select print to pdf option, to get pdf. There may be printer pre-selected and if user confirms may get this document actually printed. To avoid such situation and to provide PDF without any extras, you need to make PDF file. Probably on the server side. You could have tiny html page with invoice only and convert it to PDF file with headless chrome. It's super easy with puppeteer. No need to install/config chrome, just install npm package puppeteer (managed by chrome team) and run it. Keep in mind this will actually launch real chrome just w/o GUI, so you need to have some RAM & CPU for this. Most servers will be fine with low enough traffic.  Here is code sample but this must run on the BACKEND. Nodejs. Also it's slow call, it's resources intensive call. You should run it NOT on api call but e.g. after invoice was created - create pdf for it and store, if pdf was not generated yet, just show message to try again in couple minutes.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://your-domain.com/path-to-invoice', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
  await page.pdf({ path: 'invoice-file-path.pdf', format: 'a4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Learn more here: https://pptr.dev/

Comment: The problem with this is the pdf will not have any css effects in it.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz It will but it may not be the same as main window. You can still add custom css tho this html too.

Comment: Yeah. Iagree with you can add css in the window but how print the result in file pdf?

Comment: Does not render images, though.

Comment: @JanPi can't test it now but try adding an image as a base64 string, before it double check those paths to images are full paths, not relative.

Comment: not even able to add external style using css file, most styles are not working, but approach is good.

Comment: @PardeepJain it's HTML document you can anything to it like in normal HTML doc. Just make sure paths to CSS are full paths not relative while it's completely separated from the main dom tree.

Comment: I love this! Some tweaks here and there and it looks good. And one small thing don't remove the extra spacing at `<body >` it needs this :P

Comment: @LukasLiesis it's opening content in preview mode. what if i wants to download file without any prompt?

Comment: @pathe.kiran then you need to make that file available. If you mean pdf, then you need to create pdf and serve pdf. No matter how you will call print function, it will always show print preview, unless there is some special software/config on user side which you don't control. Updated my answer with puppeteer sample for that task.

Comment: @LukasLiesis, I tried your example with dynamic php form, but I only get the html structure of the document, but not the values. Do you know how to get user inputs together with the html part?

Comment: @ДаянаДимитрова it will print HTML from URL, if your values are in html, those will be printed. If you use PHP, you will need to render on server side. This code will literally open browser, navigate to url and print. You can read puppeteer API docs, it is possible to fill up the form or execute any JS on page after load, so maybe that's what you are looking for. But probably for your context it will be easier to just build dedicated endpoint with PHP. For 1st example it will take HTML out of page, so you could render hidden div with values from inputs inside HTML and use that div for print

Comment: Instead of `mywindow.close();` which for me closes the printing dialog too, I would recommend
    `mywindow.addEventListener("afterprint", () => mywindow.close());`

Answer (score 21):

if you need to downloadable pdf of a specific page just add button like this

```
<h4 onclick="window.print();"> Print </h4>
```

use window.print() to print your all page not just a div

Comment: Just a simple addition to it, if you wanna create a downloadable pdf of a iframe, then use the developer console: 
`document.querySelector("#myIframe").contentWindow.print()`

Comment: It doesn't print multipage HTML. only single page pdf

Comment: This will not work on chrome on Android

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned, you should use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). I've also found a function inside issues of jsPDF which splits automatically your pdf into multiple pages ([sources](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/434#issuecomment-254018569))

```
function makePDF() {

    var quotes = document.getElementById('container-fluid');

    html2canvas(quotes, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

        //! MAKE YOUR PDF
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

        for (var i = 0; i <= quotes.clientHeight/980; i++) {
            //! This is all just html2canvas stuff
            var srcImg  = canvas;
            var sX      = 0;
            var sY      = 980*i; // start 980 pixels down for every new page
            var sWidth  = 900;
            var sHeight = 980;
            var dX      = 0;
            var dY      = 0;
            var dWidth  = 900;
            var dHeight = 980;

            window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 980);
            var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
            // details on this usage of this function: 
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Slicing
            ctx.drawImage(srcImg,sX,sY,sWidth,sHeight,dX,dY,dWidth,dHeight);

            // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

            var width         = onePageCanvas.width;
            var height        = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

            //! If we're on anything other than the first page,
            // add another page
            if (i > 0) {
                pdf.addPage(612, 791); //8.5" x 11" in pts (in*72)
            }
            //! now we declare that we're working on that page
            pdf.setPage(i+1);
            //! now we add content to that page!
            pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width*.62), (height*.62));

        }
        //! after the for loop is finished running, we save the pdf.
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: it doesn't convert images

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you give any hint about how to put it to A4 page format?

Comment: This does not really make a good vector pdf, it makes a lot of bitmaps with canvas, and stacks them as images. The result has many disadvantages - large, low quality, cannot copy&paste from the PDF, etc...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jfr34mgL/ I wrote this example to cover images on multiple pages

Answer (score 18):

You can use autoPrint() and set output to 'dataurlnewwindow' like this:

```
function printPDF() {
    var printDoc = new jsPDF();
    printDoc.fromHTML($('#pdf').get(0), 10, 10, {'width': 180});
    printDoc.autoPrint();
    printDoc.output("dataurlnewwindow"); // this opens a new popup,  after this the PDF opens the print window view but there are browser inconsistencies with how this is handled
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, has this ever worked for anyone other than OP ? From reading the code, I seem to understand that it would only work with elements that have an ID. It's probably a bit more complicated than that, anyhow I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: From what I observed, very ironically, fromHTML only works if the element sent as a parameter doesn't contain any HTML: only plain text supported. Kinda kills the purpose of the whole thing imo.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. The element you want to pass in is not neccessarily required to have an ID. That's just the way that the replicant found the node he wanted to pass in. Additionally this solution also works without 'printDoc.autoPrint()'. If you want to leave this specific line in the code, then you are required to include the autoPrint-Plugin.

Comment: `.fromHTML()` has been deprecated and replaced with `.html()`

Answer (score 18):

i use [jspdf](https://github.com/mrrio/jspdf) and [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) for css rendering and i export content of specific div as this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let btn=$('#c-oreder-preview');
    btn.text('download');
    btn.on('click',()=> {

        $('#c-invoice').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            html2canvas(document.querySelector("#c-print")).then(canvas => {
                //$("#previewBeforeDownload").html(canvas);
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1);
                var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
                var pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                var pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                var imageWidth = canvas.width;
                var imageHeight = canvas.height;

                var ratio = imageWidth/imageHeight >= pageWidth/pageHeight ? pageWidth/imageWidth : pageHeight/imageHeight;
                //pdf = new jsPDF(this.state.orientation, undefined, format);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imageWidth * ratio, imageHeight * ratio);
                pdf.save("invoice.pdf");
                //$("#previewBeforeDownload").hide();
                $('#c-invoice').modal('hide');
            });
        },500);

        });
});
```

Comment: this working but it converting the content to image

Comment: Also, how to set page break so that the content/image will print on new page if it doesn't fit on current page?

Comment: for contents converted to image, name each div in a sequence, <div id='d1'> <div id='d2'> <div id='d3'> and so, and when converting them to PDF, refer to them via array....
something like this:
html2canvas($("#div_pdf"+i)[0]).then(function (canvas) {

variable i can be the result of a class in common:

var clases = document.querySelectorAll(".export_pdf");
var len = clases.length;

Comment: Merci Ghazaleh jan, you saved me some time :)

Answer (score 12):

**One way is to use window.print() function. Which does not require any library**

**Pros**

1.No external library require.

2.We can print only selected parts of body also.

3.No css conflicts and js issues.

4.Core html/js functionality

---Simply add below code

**CSS** to

```
@media print {
        body * {
            visibility: hidden; // part to hide at the time of print
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; // not necessary use         
               if colors not visible
        }

        #printBtn {
            visibility: hidden !important; // To hide 
        }

        #page-wrapper * {
            visibility: visible; // Print only required part
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
        }
    }
```

**JS code -** Call bewlow function on btn click

```
$scope.printWindow = function () {
  window.print()
}
```

**Note: Use !important in every css object**

**Example -**

```
.legend  {
  background: #9DD2E2 !important;
}
```

Comment: There are problems with Print function of the browsers. Users usually have default options selected for the Print view (margins, page size and more). Therefore, it is very difficult to produce required PDF with required styling without training user, which is way more difficult and approx impossible...

Answer (score 10):

**2022 Answer:**

To generate PDF from HTML Element and prompt to save file:

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jsPDF"

function generatePDF() {
  const doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'pt' }) // create jsPDF object
  const pdfElement = document.getElementById('pdf') // HTML element to be converted to PDF

  doc.html(pdfElement, {
    callback: (pdf) => {
      pdf.save('MyPdfFile.pdf')
    },
    margin: 32, // optional: page margin
    // optional: other HTMLOptions
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generatePDF()">Save PDF</button>
```

...

To preview PDF without printing:

```js
doc.html(pdfElement, {
  callback: (pdf) => {
    const myPdfData = pdf.output('datauristring')
  }
})
```

```html
<embed type="application/pdf" src={myPdfData} />
```

...
For more HTMLOptions:
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/types/index.d.ts

Comment: Where is it?  This one fails to load
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Comment: jsPDF can not handle complex layouts and style. Useful for only simple pages.

Comment: The html method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

Use [pdfMake.js](http://pdfmake.org/#/) and [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/64bfaa88ec24629ba492e3473ef13615).

(I found the Gist [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/205) along with a link to the package [html-to-pdfmake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdfmake), which I end up not using for now.)

After `npm install pdfmake` and saving the Gist in `htmlToPdf.js` I use it like this:

```js
const pdfMakeX = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
const pdfFontsX = require('pdfmake-unicode/dist/pdfmake-unicode.js');
pdfMakeX.vfs = pdfFontsX.pdfMake.vfs;
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import htmlToPdf from './htmlToPdf.js';

var docDef = htmlToPdf(`<b>Sample</b>`);
pdfMake.createPdf({content:docDef}).download('sample.pdf');
```

Remarks:

- My use case is to create the relevant html from a markdown document (with [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)) and subsequently generating the pdf, and uploading its binary content (which I can get with `pdfMake`'s `getBuffer()` function), all from the browser. The generated pdf turns out to be nicer for this kind of html than with other solutions I have tried.
- I am dissatisfied with the results I got from `jsPDF.fromHTML()` suggested in the accepted answer, as that solution gets easily confused by special characters in my HTML that apparently are interpreted as a sort of markup and totally mess up the resulting PDF.
- Using canvas based solutions (like the deprecated `jsPDF.from_html()` function, not to be confused with the one from the accepted answer) is not an option for me since I want the text in the generated PDF to be pasteable, whereas canvas based solutions generate bitmap based PDFs.
- Direct markdown to pdf converters like [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf) are server side only and would not work for me.
- Using the printing functionality of the browser would not work for me as I do not want to display the generated PDF but upload its binary content.

Comment: If I read the code correctly, this does not support CSS border styles (e.g. on tables), correct?

Comment: Off topic, I use pdfmake to create pdf with the content not from html. My question is : how to provide our own specific file name instead of random file name resulted when using its method : pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open() ?

Comment: Now on-topic, the gist you mentioned does not exist. What is the problem with html-to-pdfmake which you said you ended up not using it ? I saw in the github it was still maintained recently.

Comment: Best solution by far.
I don't get why jsPDF answers are all over the place and pdfmake is never mentionned.
I get a searchable text PDF created with ease.
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get jsPDF to print dynamically created tables from a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#pdfDiv").click(function() {

    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
    var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#rentalListCan': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
        }
    };

    pdf.addHTML($('#rentalListCan').first(), function() {
        pdf.save("caravan.pdf");
    });
    });
});
```

Works great with Chrome and Firefox... formatting is all blown up in IE.

I also included these:

```
<script src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js"></script>
    <script src="//mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/Blob.js/Blob.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/deflate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/adler32cs.js/adler32cs.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
```

Comment: can u pls post example how u pass html

Comment: but your code is  <script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>   which means it needs internet ?

Comment: @Erum you can download the File.

Answer (score 2):

Dissatisfied with the rendering of html2canvas and lack of modern CSS3/JS and print specific CSS support of pdfMake's outdated version of WebKit...

Here's a theoretical solution, it's headless and can render pages faithfully, supports page breaks, margins, different page sizes and can be automated. You can even render WebGl to PDF.

- Chrome has a devtools protocol... which has a printtoPDF function

  - Excerpt: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/new
  - Official 20k-SLOC spec: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/blob/master/json/browser_protocol.json
- You can use node and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher to run chrome headless... wait for it to render.
- Profit

printToPDF command you'd run on chrome_devtools protocol:

```
printToPDF({
  printBackground: false,
  pageWidth: 8.5,
  pageHeight: 11,
  transferMode: "ReturnAsStream" // or ReturnAsBase64
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export a table, you can take a look at [this export sample](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/export-to-pdf) provided by the Shield UI Grid widget.

It is done by extending the configuration like this:

```
...
exportOptions: {
    proxy: "/filesaver/save",
    pdf: {
        fileName: "shieldui-export",
        author: "John Smith",
        dataSource: {
            data: gridData
        },
        readDataSource: true,
        header: {
            cells: [
                { field: "id", title: "ID", width: 50 },
                { field: "name", title: "Person Name", width: 100 },
                { field: "company", title: "Company Name", width: 100 },
                { field: "email", title: "Email Address" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: The "Export to PDF" functionality resulted in an empty PDF document.

Comment: Probably wrong configuration on your end... If you want, post a question with the shieldui tag

Answer (score 1):

This example works great.

```
<button onclick="genPDF()">Generate PDF</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function genPDF() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
        doc.addPage();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
    
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Though this answer introduces a js to pdf library, The question is to create pdf from the contents of an HTML element and not manually creating the pdf's structure with code.

Answer (score 1):

The following method works fine for my case.

Hide additional parts for a page like the following example

```
@media print{
    body{
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; // if you want to enable graphics
        color-adjust: exact !important; // if you want to enable graphics
        print-color-adjust: exact !important; // if you want to enable graphics
       
        * {
            visibility: hidden;
            margin:0;
            padding:0
        }
        .print_area, .print_area *{
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .print_area{
            margin: 0;
            align: center;
        }
        .pageBreak { 
           page-break-before : always; // If you want to skip next page
           page-break-inside: avoid;  // If you want to skip next page
         }
      }
    @page {
        size: A4; margin:0mm; // set page layout
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Use the javascript print function to print execution.

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

it helped me [https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/#:~:text=Convert%20HTML%20Content%20to%20PDF%20with%20Images%20and%20Multiple%20Pages](https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/#:%7E:text=Convert%20HTML%20Content%20to%20PDF%20with%20Images%20and%20Multiple%20Pages)

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.
var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#contentToPrint");

doc.html(elementHTML, {
    callback: function(doc) {
        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('document-html.pdf');
    },
    margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],
    autoPaging: 'text',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 190, //target width in the PDF document
    windowWidth: 675 //window width in CSS pixels
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture div as PDF you can use https://grabz.it solution. It's got a JavaScript API which is easy and flexible and will allow you to capture the contents of a single HTML element such as a div or a span

In order to implement it you will need to first get an [app key and secret](https://grabz.it/api/#Key) and [download](https://grabz.it/api/javascript/download.ashx) the (free) SDK.

And now an example.

Let's say you have the HTML:

```
<div id="features">
    <h4>Acme Camera</h4>
    <label>Price</label>$399<br />
    <label>Rating</label>4.5 out of 5
</div>
<p>Cras ut velit sed purus porttitor aliquam. Nulla tristique magna ac libero tempor, ac vestibulum felisvulput ate. Nam ut velit eget
risus porttitor tristique at ac diam. Sed nisi risus, rutrum a metus suscipit, euismod tristique nulla. Etiam venenatis rutrum risus at
blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus eget vehicula felis.</p>
```

To capture what is under the features id you will need to:

```
//add the sdk
<script type="text/javascript" src="grabzit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//login with your key and secret. 
GrabzIt("KEY", "SECRET").ConvertURL("http://www.example.com/my-page.html",
{"target": "#features", "format": "pdf"}).Create();
</script>
```

Please note the `target: #feature`. `#feature` is you CSS selector, like in the previous example. Now, when the page is loaded an image screenshot will now be created in the same location as the script tag, which will contain all of the contents of the features div and nothing else.

The are other configuration and customization you can do to the div-screenshot mechanism, please check them out [here](https://grabz.it/api/javascript/capturediv.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

any one try this

```js
    (function () {  
        var  
         form = $('.form'),  
         cache_width = form.width(),  
         a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  

        $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {  
            $('body').scrollTop(0);  
            createPDF();  
        });  
        //create pdf  
        function createPDF() {  
            getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {  
                var  
                 img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),  
                 doc = new jsPDF({  
                     unit: 'px',  
                     format: 'a4'  
                 });  
                doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);  
                doc.save('Bhavdip-html-to-pdf.pdf');  
                form.width(cache_width);  
            });  
        }  

        // create canvas object  
        function getCanvas() {  
            form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');  
            return html2canvas(form, {  
                imageTimeout: 2000,  
                removeContainer: true  
            });  
        }  

    }());
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick, dirty, gets the job done.

** No clickable text on the PDF **

1. Screenshots the `div` using `html2canvas`. Returns a canvas element.
2. Puts the `canvas` element on a pdf using `jsPDF`

```js
const handleDownloadPDF = () => {
  const domElement = document.getElementById('print');
  if (domElement) {
    html2canvas(domElement).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new JSPDF();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(), pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
      pdf.save(`${new Date().toISOString()}.pdf`);
    });
  }
};
```

3. You can always skip the PDF part if not needed and directly download the canvas as a png or jpg. This won't require `jsPDF` library

```
const handleDownloadPng = () => {
  const domElement = document.getElementById('print');

  html2canvas(domElement).then(canvas => {
    // Convert canvas to a PNG data URL
    const pngDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    // Create a download link
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = pngDataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = "div-image.png";
    downloadLink.textContent = "Download PNG";

    // Append the link and trigger a click
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  });
}
```