# convert html page to pdf from jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html2pdf

i have designed a page in html. i need to find a way to save the html body section as pdf. can some one suggest me a jquery plugin where i can get this work done?

am using C# as my back end coding.

Comment: this ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript