# jsPDF settings for printing leaflet/openlayers map

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I came across jsNode library here [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)
So I've installed. I'm tryna use it to print a leaflet map. It seems I was not able to set it propely. It create the PDF but nothing shows on the map. Could you help me with that ?

**Javascript**

```
function genPDF() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {
        '#ignorePDF': function(element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    doc.fromHTML(
        source,
        15,
        15, {
            'width': 180,
            'elementHandlers': elementHandler
        });

    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");

}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body onload="Create_MAP();">
        <div id="map">
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="bt" value="PRINT PDF" onclick="genPDF();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your leaflet map into an image first.

You can use https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image

Then add that image to jsPDF for export.

Comment: Wow... I'll try and do that then. Thanks bud