# html to pdf conversion resulting into blank pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am using code suggested in following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript). Following is the function for pdf conversion which i have used.

```
function pdfGenerator(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();    
    var elementHandler = {
              '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
              }
            };
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    doc.fromHTML(
        source,
        15,
        15,
        {
          'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
        });

    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
}
```

I have downloaded latest version mentioned in the following [link](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and added it as external jar. Can u pleases suggest how to include scripts of

- `jspdf.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.from_html.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js`
- `jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js`

in my project? I am getting blank pdf as output.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried changing to resolve issues? any fiddle?

Comment: Try adding a `timeout` function to your `doc.output("dataurlnewwindow')` statement like, `setTimeout(function(){doc.output("dataurlnewwindow")},1000);`

Comment: I am stuck at adding plugin scripts.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/radhika16/yj9arhmw/

Answer (score 0):

You can use defer attribute of script tag.

```
<script defer src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script defer src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script defer src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script defer src="jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script defer src="/* YOUR SCRIPT HERE */"></script>
```

This way all scripts will be loaded synchroniously, one after one.
[More info @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Hey! I have added scripts as u have suggested and removed removed the zip file of jspdf which i had added externally. But, now no pdf is generated and i am getting following error in chrome console                                       jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:424 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedGetCSS @ jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:424DrillForContent @ jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:492process @ jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:550jsPDFAPI.fromHTML @ jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:591pdfGenerator @ prefilledform.js:37onclick @ DayCare.jsp:111

Comment: It seems this code is using **jquery** inside itself, so simply add `<script defer src="/* SRC TO JQUERY */"></script>` in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `.save` function instead of `doc.output` to make it as a downloadable pdf, Ensure that you have placed this inside a `settimeout` statement as well. Here is the refined code.

```
function pdfGenerator(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();    
    var elementHandler = {
              '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
              }
            };
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    doc.fromHTML(
        source,
        15,
        15,
        {
          'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
        });

       setTimeout(function(){
          doc.save('test');
       },2000);
}
```

Hope this helps!