# Angular Js HTML to PDF

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, ngtable, jspdf-autotable

I have my data in angular table (JSON) format. Anyone know how to convert it to PDF file.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have tried with any code? if yes then please add here so we can improve.

Comment: Try to search for 'javascript pdf generator' and you will find something like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) or [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) that might work. If you try to convert the table alone you could try [jsPDF with some plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825130/510711), and use the tables html as a starter.. don't know if it works.

Comment: You could have shown at least a little effort of what you tried and where you failed. If you didn't even know where to start I hope my previous comment helped :-)

Comment: I have tried jsPDF but i'm little bit confused to do it in angular way. @flob

Comment: jsPDF itself must be wrapped in some directive if you want to do it the angular way :-) But maybe the answer from kuns helps you already.. :-)

Comment: Yes It works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this,
[angular-save-html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-save-html-to-pdf)

this module converts the HTML to HTML5 canvas and captures the same and converts it to PDF.

Hope this helps you.