# Creating printable document from page data

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'd like to take some data from webpage and create a printable document from it. I've got a script and template for printing (in html and a file), so my question is: how can I generate that kind of document? Where can I put this template? Am I supposed to create document from data or put prepared document somewhere (where and how :) ) and insert data in it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Read this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)