# Exporting web page as PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I have SVG images, and lot of text with inline CSS, in an HTML page. I need to export all of them into PDF. Suggest to me proper technology which caters to my need. I am using JavaScript and jQuery as front end and Python as backend.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried jsPDF, but it is not preserving the CSS styling and I am not able to export images also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @Cristyan that package will not preserve the css styling while exporting as PDF

Comment: @freginold i have tried jsPdf, but it is not preserving the CSS styling and i am not able to export images also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it **server-side**, there's a python package for that:

- http://weasyprint.org/

Otherwise, you can do it **in the browser** but *you will loose the CSS*.
jsPDF appears to have experimental support for converting HTML to a PDF, or you can programmatically populate a PDF document with similar content. SVG is supported via plugin.

Demo:

- http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Github:

- https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: will that package preserves the HTML css styling while exporting to PDF

Comment: jsPDF doesn't seem able to handle more than basic CSS.  See [this issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1384) for more detail.

Comment: jsPDF is not a great option if you want to preserve CSS. If you can do it server-side, I recommend that. I edited the post with a server-side option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) command line tools? I was in a project where I also needed to convert a web page to  PDF and I used this library (I used PHP as backend) and it worked very well for me.

I hope I have helped :D

Comment: But in my case i am not using PHP as backend, will it work for me with python

Comment: Unfortunately, I never worked with Python. But I used this commands with function "exec()" of PHP. Therefore, if you can "simulate The implementation of an external program" in Python, I think that go work.

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: Ok. Sorry if I not helped you

Comment: @SBNAB See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) for some ways to call external programs with Python.

Comment: Perfect! That's right! If is using Ubuntu, try something as: call("path_dir_of_wkhtmltopdf  path_your_page_here path_your_pdf_here");