# PL/SQL Content to PDF print in Oracle Apex 5.1.3

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I designed invoice by PL/SQL content with HTML and CSS but I can't set up properly page. And I can't print in PDF format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you just started with Apex, perhaps you'd rather use its Wizards which will help you in creating process. Although you can create a page using HTML commands - why would you?

Invoice is, I presume, stored into a table. If that's so, I'd suggest you to create a "Report with form on table" page - it'll create

- interactive report, which will let you browse through all invoices you created
- form, which will let you create new invoices, update or delete existing ones

Try it; it shouldn't be difficult at all.

As of printing reports in PDF format: here's what I (we) do:

- I create a report using Oracle Reports Builder
- put a RDF onto our IAS (Internet Application Server) machine
- place its entry into the CGICMD.DAT file
- call the report from Apex using a dynamic action on a button, using 2 steps:

  - PL/SQL, which composes URL (and adds parameters' values)
  - JavaScript, which calls the report (using `window.open`)

I understand that not everyone has the IAS up and running; it isn't trivial task at all. Quite some time ago, for my own amusement, I installed Apache Tomcat and JasperReports, just to see if I can make it work. I did. However, as my company uses IAS & Oracle Reports, I *abandoned* that approach.

Someone else might have other suggestions; wait a little bit for them to answer.