# Save PDF from window.print in Javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

Good day,

I'm able to print a page using javascript. Using this codes:

```
var win = window.open('', 'print', 'height=720,width=300');
...

win.document.write(document.getElementById("myDivToPrint").innerHTML);

win.document.close(); 
win.focus();
win.print();
```

But my problem is, is there a way to save this on my server api? 
I tried this,

```
var myPdf = win.output(); // Doesn't work, not found
```

I want to get at least the encoding of the pdf to be able to save it on my server. Is it possible? if yes, please help me how.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use print if you want to save the PDF as print uses the browser print function.

if you use jQuery check this previous post [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

You'll need to convert the HTML in PDF and then send a request to your server to save the file

Comment: I don't use jquery

Comment: the problem with that package is that you can use external stylesheet