# I want to send email with pdf of current web page in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, email, pdf

1) I am currently downloading pdf of web-page using function window.print()
2)but now i want to send that downloaded pdf in email as a attachment.
3)I am not able to access that pdf in my code

how i will be able to send that email with pdf in just one click?

Comment: ` 3)I am not able to access that pdf in my code` you can use the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) API to handle local binaries.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636428/save-pdf-from-window-print-to-js-var/54713587#54713587

Answer (score 0):

You can try get a screenshot of your window then put it on a pdf.

see this two plugins

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf