# Print PDF in Chrome from HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, firefox, acrobat

I have a problem :

I need to print a PDF from an html document.
All images sizes together are around 16Mo.
And my final PDF with Chrome is like 150 Mo.

I tried to do the same with Adobe Acrobat on Chrome but he only print the document like an image. I can't search a text in the document... (but the size is like 8Mo)

I tried on Firefox but the render is completely different... (font-size are a lot smaller, even pixels size write in the css...) But it  prints a selectable text (so i can do the ctrl+f) and the file is around 10 Mo (with acrobat))

Do you know how can i print with acrobat in chrome to have text and images and not a BIG image from the HTML code ? (in order to have a file < 20Mo and that i could do a ctrl+F)

Thank you :)

Comment: If you're talking about manually, you can use the Chrome Print dialog and select `Send to PDF`. If you're looking for code to do it automatically, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript.

Comment: The chrome print, is the first I tried and it make a PDF file around 130Mo.
I found a solution like that : I save the html file and I make a PDF with acrobat. and it works (around 10Mo and i can select the text). But it's not automatic..

Comment: Then what is the issue? As far as I can see, you are asking for a way to convert an HTML page to a PDF file?

Comment: I found a solution using the Adobe Reader extension for chrome. The file is around 4Mo vs 130Mo of Chrome pdf.