# How to show html string response as a Pdf in subscribe angular method call (button click)

Tags: html, angular, pdf, angular6

I am stuck at one of the issue where I have a anchor tag in a component , on click of It ,I have a post method which is posting some data into service and in response I am getting report data as a html string , Now client wants to see the report as a PDF in a new window . How to achieve this ,there are lots of articles but none of it resolved ,need some simple solution . Somewhere I read to convert html string in service to byte of array using encode and then Create Url Object (front end -Blob) but that is also not working. I dont have the exact code but a kind of replica I just shared ,any help would be great.

```
<a (click)= "openreport(request)" /> 


openreport(request) {

this.dataservice.postdata('service url' ,request).subscribe(res= >{

res.creditreportdata---> html string


})

}
```

Comment: report means ssrs reports

Comment: no its just a string in html format ,I want to show that as a PDF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten that article was not helpful for me ,can you give me some simple solution to achieve this

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-using-angular-6/