# How to export grid data to excel, csv and pdf files (React)

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an application in **React and .NET Core API**. I have created mine grid (not using any npm package for this).

There is functionality required to **export grid data to pdf, excel and csv format**. How can i achieve this without any npm package or library?

I will get data(in List) form server (.NET core API) on download click button.

I have tried some npm packages like *react-csv, downloadjs* but they are not working as expected.

> Mine data in array of objects format:

```
[{firstColumn: "1", secondCoulmn: "4", thirdColumn: "test"},
 {firstColumn: "2", secondCoulmn: "3", thirdColumn: "test2"}]
```

When i am passing this data in ***downloadjs*** then excel file having [Object object] content and PDF file generated is corrupted.

For ***react-csv*** it is generating unknown file like *b0d7cfd9-f4ca-4792-bfad-2b3198c63a33*

Comment: Tell us what specific problems you're having with react-csv and/or downloadjs so we can help you solve them. Include your code, please.

Comment: csv is possible without any library but in case of xls and pdf you have to use the libraries

Comment: @stone i have added more details.

Comment: @NihalSaxena could you please share idea of doing this?

Comment: sure @SandeepRasgotra i have added a answer please check weather it works for you

Comment: I meant post your code that attempts to solve the problem. Not the data. On StackOverflow we expect question askers to have tried it themselves first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data is grid you want to export

In case of csv :

```
const csvContent = data.map(d=>d.join(",")).join("\n")
const element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute(
  'href',
  `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ${encodeURIComponent(csvContent)}`,
);
element.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.csv`);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

if data is complex you may use [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse)

```
const csvContent = Papa.unparse(data);
```

In case of Xls :

use [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library

example :

```
const sheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, sheet, 'Sheet 1');
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${fileName}.xls`);
```

In case of pdf:

you need to create the html of grid

then you can use the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library:

[Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

Comment: it worked for Excel and CSV and it is really helpful, but i am still searching for pdf solution.

Comment: what problem are you facing in creating pdf ?

Comment: In this solution for pdf we can converthtml to pdf. In mine scenario  i need to export all data to pdf which is currently not in html because i amshowning limited records on grid like 10 , so in this scenario this is not feasible solution.

Comment: In that case you have to simply create PDF with multiple pages

Comment: if you can share the code snippet i can show you how to do it