# PHP to PDFconversion using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert the table data into pdf using jquery.it is not working .When I click on the button it does not convert.It appears that the submit button is not at all working

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="classification" content="" />
        <title>Geochronology Asset Management System | Add Sample</title>
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE  -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(e){
        console.log("test")
        $("#pdf1").click(function(e){
            $("#tablepdf").tableExport({
                type:'pdf',
                escape:'false'
            });
        });
    });

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>


<h2>Export Data to pdf with PHP and MySQL</h2>

<button  id="pdf1"  class="btn btn-info">Export to pdf</button>

<table id="tablepdf" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
  </body>
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- For PDF-->
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</html>
```

can anyone suggest me what is wrong in my code,I have included all library function .Is there any problem with sequence of the library files ??

Comment: what error are you getting in console

Comment: @AmanjotKaur it is not giving any error .But the button not working not able to convert into PDF

Comment: Are you using jspdf to convert to pdf? If yes, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript