# Download content from bootstrap modal

Tags: html, download

I'm showing content of a report in the body of a bootstrap modal. There is a download button in the footer. What I want is to download the html content of the modal body as a pdf or smt when the download button is clicked.

Comment: you can use jsPDF plugin see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks. So there is no any inbuild way to do it right?