# vue html to pdf without html2canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, pdf, vuejs2

I currently need to create a pdf file from HTML or Vue component.
I have tried `jsPDF`, `html2pdf`, `vue-html2pdf` but it looks like these libraries using html2canvas which mean it's freeze UI in few seconds (depends on HTML structure) and can't run inside web worker.
So my questions: **how to generate pdf from HTML without using html2canvas or using web worker to avoid freeze UI**

I believe this can be achieved because reactjs have [react-pdf](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf) which create pdf without using canvas

Comment: You can try pdfmake: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake. Look like it use pdfkit, just like react-pdf

Comment: @CuongNgocLe pdfmake is not convert HTML to pdf entirely, it uses table layout so very difficult with complicated UI. react-pdf look like have a bunch of class before using pdfkit, I'm not good at react so I don't quite understand what they are doing

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help your problem but [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890644/15958543)  a way to printing a pdf without using third party libraries is explained. It uses print property of the window.

Comment: it's create pdf indeed but i can't retrieve the pdf from main window

Comment: i want to create pdf file to preview but i don't want to download it, like create a blob to view on web

Answer (score 0):

you can use `javascript` and `jquery` to print it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>html2pdf</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam id, ex
      facere perferendis eligendi corporis provident ipsam, ea porro debitis
      natus aut nulla, ipsa atque aliquam architecto est dolorem impedit!
    </div>
    <button id="btn">print content</button>

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $('#btn').click(function () {
        var divContents = $('#page').html()
        var printWindow = window.open('', '_self', 'height=400,width=800')
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>html2pdf</title>')
        
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body>')
        printWindow.document.write(divContents)
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>')
        printWindow.document.close()
        printWindow.print()
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can also add style css to the page
by add this line between `head` tag, if `html` file and `css` file in same folder

```
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />')
```

Comment: But this doesn't create a PDF. It just opens a dialog to print.

Comment: @tony19 is right, your solution doesn't create a file (Blob), it open the print dialog to download

Comment: yeah it open a dialog, but you can print that pdf