# HTML div to PDF in Javascript - Error text not selectable

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial to create a resume in HTML/CSS/JS. The problem is to export this resume in pdf (actually one div): when I export it like in the video (with html2pdf.bundle.min.js) it transforms the page in the image than in pdf. But I want to keep the text selectable and really transform my HTML div into a pdf (text and layout).

Comment: Check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Comment: "html2pdf.js renders all content into an image, then places that image into a PDF" therefore making it impossible to produce a PDF with selectable text. If i'm not mistaken PDF.js supports text selection so you may want to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This code :

HTML :

```
  <h1>Book : A Brief History of Time</h1>
  <h1>Writer : Stephen Hawking</h1>
  <h1>Publisher : Bantam Books</h1>
  <h1>Subject: Cosmology</h1>
  <h1>Gener : Space</h1>       

  <button onclick="genPDF()">Generate PDF</button>
```

Script :

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script>

        var elementHandler = {
        '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
        };
        var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        function genPDF() {              

            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.fromHTML(
             // print DOC Body to PDF file
            source,
            15,
            15,
            {
            'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
            });
            doc.save('Test.pdf');
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: For those coming here from 2024 onwards, the fromHTML method no longer exists.