# save content of page to pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, web

I'm a helpless beginner when it comes to web development and coding, but I have abit more than 600 individual html pages (like pages of a book) and I'd like to write a function that iterates through pages using their adresses (file:///C:/Users/user/messages*.html) and save the content as pdf, then stitch them together.
can anyone help me achieve that?

Comment: That's overkill, don't do that with javascript. find a pdf app to do that, google HTML to pdf. Don't try to solve every problem with web dev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)