# jsPDF convert HTML to PDF - Formatting

Tags: html, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF and it is already passing something of the HTML page to the PDF. We have the following Code:

HTML:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" contentType="text/html"
applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" id="TestSampleInvoice">
<apex:stylesheet value="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef"/>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />              

    <style>
        .invoice-box {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
            font-family: Open-Sans, sans-serif;
            color: #555;
        }

        .invoice-box table {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: inherit;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .invoice-box table td {
            padding: 5px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
            font-size: 45px;
            line-height: 45px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
            background: #eee;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.details td {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
            border-top: 2px solid #eee;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        /** RTL **/
        .invoice-box.rtl {
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .invoice-box.rtl table {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .invoice-box.rtl table tr td:nth-child(2) {
            text-align: left;
        }
        
  .alef {
    font-family: 'Alef', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
  }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="invoice-box">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="top">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title">
                                <img src="https://www.ailo-it.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Ailo-IT-e1589191157673.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Invoice #: 123<br />
                                Created: January 1, 2015<br />
                                Due: February 1, 2015
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="information alef">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Ailo-IT<br />
                                Dreifürstensteinstr. 1-3<br />
                                72116 Mössingen
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                Customer Name<br />
                                Firstname Lastname<br />
                                email@example.com
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="heading" style="font-family:Tahoma">
                <td>Payment Method</td>

                <td>Check #</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="details">
                <td>Check</td>

                <td>1000</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="heading">
                <td>Item</td>

                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item">
                <td>Website design</td>

                <td>$300.00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item">
                <td>Hosting (3 months)</td>

                <td>$75.00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="item last">
                <td>Domain name (1 year)</td>

                <td>$10.00</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="total">
                <td></td>

                <td>Total: $385.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

which already results in a proper looking HTML Page:
[HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMHhx.png)

On that HTML Page we have added a button to download the PDF using JSPDF:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.3.6/purify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style> 
.alef {
    font-family: 'Alef', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
</style>
<body>
    <apex:outputText id="pdfContent" value="{!invoiceDataString}" escape="false">
  <button value="Generate PDF" onclick="createPDF()">Generate PDF</button>
<script>
    function createPDF(){
     const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
                        encryption: {
                            userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
                        }
                    });

 pdf.html(document.getElementById('{!$Component.pdfContent}'), {
                       callback: function (pdf) {
                         pdf.save('test.pdf');
                       },
                      
                    });
}
```

But the generated PDF is not at all formatted. **My question is**, where to find any documentation on how to pass the HTML value to the PDF to use the applied styling and everything.

Current result can be downloaded here: [Generated PDF](https://ailo-app-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/7Q000000KTQM/a/7Q000000oNpX/ijLmcSA.X2jDzBiJ304F7apyWB3YCO3r9p53u5nvNDs)

Comment: check this answer it might be what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript

Comment: Hi Abdelmoula, thanks for the link that helps already. But still can't find anything about custom font support.