# Cannot load html2 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/lib/dummy.js"
    
  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
    /* EOS */
  </style>

  <script id="insert"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <head>
  <style>
      @CHARSET "UTF-8";
    .page-break {
      page-break-after: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      clear:both;
    }
    .page-break-before {
      page-break-before: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      clear:both;
    }
    #html-2-pdfwrapper{
      position: absolute; 
      left: 20px; 
      top: 50px; 
      bottom: 0; 
      overflow: auto; 
      width: 600px;
    }
   
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>
  <div id="html-2-pdfwrapper">
    <h3 class= "first_header-txt">
      Net Weight (KG/LB)
    </h3>
    <h3 class="first-txt">
      Temp1
    </h3>
    
    <h3 class= "second_header-txt">
      Gross Weight (KG/LB)
    </h3>
    <h3 class="second-txt">
      Temp2
    </h3>
    <h3 class="details">
      Temp3
    </h3>
    <div>
</body>

<script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
    var base64Img = null;
    margins = {
      top: 70,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 30,
      width: 550
    };
    
    generate = function()
{
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.setFontSize(18);
  pdf.html(document.getElementById('html-2-pdfwrapper'), 

    {
    'x' : margins.left, // x coord
    'y' : margins.top,
    'width' : margins.width,// max width of content on PDF
    'callback' : function(pdf) {
        pdf.save('NetWeight.pdf');
    }

    });
    
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:650px; padding:20px;');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  
  iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
};
    
    </script>
<script>
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          var obj = JSON.parse(json_object);
          var length = obj.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var netWeight = obj[i]["netWeight"];
                var grossWeight = obj[i]["grossWeight"];
                var details = obj[i]["details"];
                chumpage(netWeight, grossWeight, details);
          }
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };
  function chumpage(netWeight, grossWeight, details) {
    var netWeight = netWeight;
    var grossWeight = grossWeight;
    var details = details;
    var netWeightKG = Math.trunc(grossWeight * 2.2);
    var grossWeightKG = Math.trunc(grossWeight * 2.2);
  chump = document.getElementsByClassName("first-txt");
  chump2 = document.getElementsByClassName("second-txt");
  chump3 = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
  chump[0].style.fontSize = "100px";
  chump2[0].style.fontSize = "100px";
  chump3[0].style.fontSize = "50px";
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length; i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = netWeight + '/' + netWeightKG;
    chump2[i].innerText = grossWeight + '/' + grossWeightKG;
    chump3[i].innerText = details;
  }
}
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
</form>



<script>
  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Whenever I try to generate pdf on the website I get the error cannot load html2 canvas and the pdf is blank. The above code takes in rows from an excel sheet with 3 values and creates a page with said values, currently I am just trying to get the pdf to work before i go and use jsPDF to create multiple pages. Thanks for advance in any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the source of jsPDF as it was done in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript), it seems to have worked:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script> --> <!-- --##### REMOVED -->
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/lib/dummy.js"
    
  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
    /* EOS */
  </style>

  <script id="insert"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <head>
  <style>
      @CHARSET "UTF-8";
    .page-break {
      page-break-after: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      clear:both;
    }
    .page-break-before {
      page-break-before: always;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      clear:both;
    }
    #html-2-pdfwrapper{
      position: absolute; 
      left: 20px; 
      top: 50px; 
      bottom: 0; 
      overflow: auto; 
      width: 600px;
    }
   
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>
  <div id="html-2-pdfwrapper">
    <h3 class= "first_header-txt">
      Net Weight (KG/LB)
    </h3>
    <h3 class="first-txt">
      Temp1
    </h3>
    
    <h3 class= "second_header-txt">
      Gross Weight (KG/LB)
    </h3>
    <h3 class="second-txt">
      Temp2
    </h3>
    <h3 class="details">
      Temp3
    </h3>
    <div>
</body>

<script>
    //window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF --##### REMOVED

    var base64Img = null;
    margins = {
      top: 70,
      bottom: 40,
      left: 30,
      width: 550
    };
    
    generate = function()
{
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.setFontSize(18);

  //pdf.html(document.getElementById('html-2-pdfwrapper'), --##### REMOVED

  pdf.fromHTML(document.getElementById('html-2-pdfwrapper'), 

    {
    'x' : margins.left, // x coord
    'y' : margins.top,
    'width' : margins.width,// max width of content on PDF
    'callback' : function(pdf) {
        pdf.save('NetWeight.pdf');
    }

    });
    
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:650px; padding:20px;');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  
  iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
};
    
    </script>
<script>
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          var obj = JSON.parse(json_object);
          var length = obj.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var netWeight = obj[i]["netWeight"];
                var grossWeight = obj[i]["grossWeight"];
                var details = obj[i]["details"];
                chumpage(netWeight, grossWeight, details);
          }
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };
  function chumpage(netWeight, grossWeight, details) {
    var netWeight = netWeight;
    var grossWeight = grossWeight;
    var details = details;
    var netWeightKG = Math.trunc(grossWeight * 2.2);
    var grossWeightKG = Math.trunc(grossWeight * 2.2);
  chump = document.getElementsByClassName("first-txt");
  chump2 = document.getElementsByClassName("second-txt");
  chump3 = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
  chump[0].style.fontSize = "100px";
  chump2[0].style.fontSize = "100px";
  chump3[0].style.fontSize = "50px";
  for (var i = 0; i < chump.length; i++) {
    chump[i].innerText = netWeight + '/' + netWeightKG;
    chump2[i].innerText = grossWeight + '/' + grossWeightKG;
    chump3[i].innerText = details;
  }
}
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
</form>



<script>
  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```