# Java Vaadin - How to save/export content of Panel with scroll to PDF or JPEG?

Tags: java, image, pdf, vaadin, jpeg

Like in title.

Is there some simply way to save/export content of Panel with scroll to PDF or JPEG??

Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a generic HTML to PDF conversion question, so here’s a related Q&A for that: [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

Then how to integrate JS stuff in Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/element-api/client-server-rpc

Comment: That advice can be usefull. Not simple way, but it gives me some direction to resolve the problem. Thank you.