# Convert AEM page to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, aem, html-to-pdf

I want to convert AEM html page to Pdf (using AEM 6.5)  and a link will be provided to users for to download that PDF.

The AEM page is a Product Description Page with mutiple tabs and also contains images and tables.
Hence, can you please suggest the best way I can achieve this (preferably open source) and also have control on the styling on the content in the generated PDF?

Comment: There is no "best" way :). I would try in the FrontEnd e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825130/1514647

Comment: AEM comes with Apache FOP to create it in the back-end, there you can have access to all the details that should be printed. For styling you can use XSL.