# How do I convert HTML to PDF using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

Currently, I use html2pdf.js to generate PDFs using HTML, but I need a little more customisation. How can I create the same setup using jsPDF and, if necessary, html2canvas?

The following is my current setup:

```
async function downloadPDF() {
  const element = document.getElementById("report");

  const options = {
    image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.95 },
    html2canvas: { scale: 3 },
    jsPDF: {
      format: "a4",
      orientation: "portrait",
    },
    margin: [12, 0],
    pagebreak: { avoid: ".section", mode: "css" },
  };
  const fileName = "test_123"

  await html2pdf()
    .from(element)
    .set(options)
    .save(`${fileName}.pdf`);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893/generate-pdf-from-html-in-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @Justinas Thanks, I saw that answer, but unfortunately, .fromHTML is deprecated. I tried almost every guide I could find online, but I either generate a blank page or my content is so zoomed in that nothing is distinguishable.

Comment: Seems like it should be replaced with `.html()`: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2852